# Java multithreaded http Range bytes usage is failing

Tags: java, multithreading, http, range

I'm working on a multithreaded downloader feature in order to maximize bandwidth usage. Each thread is downloading a part of target file relying on Http Range capability. (I'm checking remote host is supporting such of course). Roughly my thread run() code is the following :

```
HttpURLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
urlConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + currentByte + "-" + endByte);

if (urlConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_PARTIAL) {
 // I'm OK
} else {
 // :-(
}
```

My issue is only first thread is getting 206 code response ... others are getting 200 code.
I've x2 checked currentByte and endByte values all such are ok (no overlap, no out of bounds, ...). So ??? I'm stucked. Any advice ?
Thks.

Comment: And you are sure that the values for currentByte, endByte are correct for your various threads? Does it makes a difference when you go for 2, 4, n threads? Are you sure your server does actually supports this? Those are the things you should include in such a question. From your description enough there isnt much we could do.

Comment: All is working fine if single thread.
My target is to rely on 4 threads. At that time I'm facing issue except if target file is quite small i.e. less than 1Mb to be downloaded per thread.
Yes my server is supporting this (I'm checking header first). Yes current & end bytes are all ok.
As working for small files I'm wondering if any http / server limit to Range usage ? ... or as small part process time is quite fast so not leading to thread unsafe issues ...

Comment: Working on a multithreaded downloaded feature does not maximise bandwidth usage, especially for small files. It only multiples the number of connection setup and teardown packets.

Comment: ok I agree. My final usage is for sure for huge files. Small file as target is suitable for debug purpose.

Comment: And what have you received in fact? Maybe just the server answers with 200 (which means OK) instead of 206, and everything else is as you expect?

Comment: Getting 206 code then using urlConn.getContentLengthLong() I'm getting right partial target file length.
Getting 200 code then using urlConn.getContentLengthLong() I'm getting full target file length.
... what's not helping me ... by then end I'm getting one target file part plus 3 times the full file :-(

Comment: I've found such comment : "When multiple ranges are requested, a server MAY coalesce any of the ranges that overlap, or that are separated by a gap that is smaller than the overhead of sending multiple parts, regardless of the order in which the corresponding byte-range-spec appeared in the received Range header field"

Can it be the clue ? Is there a way to prevent coalesce process ? On my side no overlap but gap is 0 (joined parts download)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418230/http-range-request-property